# How to pass parameter like x>1 to ifelse function

Tags: r, sapply, grepl

I have a data.frame like

```
Age
1
2
3
4
5
```

I would like to make new variable "AgeGR"

```
getAgeGR = function(x) {
  xInt = as.integer(x)
  ifelse( grepl(0, xInt), "Puppy", 
          ifelse(grepl(|What to put here|, xInt), "Young", 
                 ifelse(grepl(8, xInt), "Adult","Old") ))}

df$AgeGR = sapply(df$Age, getAgeGR)
```

I don't know "What to put here". I was trying

```
x>1
>1
```

It only works when I put one number.

Comment: You may need to look into `?cut` to create bins of data

Comment: `cut(df$Age, breaks=c(0,3,8,9,Inf), labels=c("Puppy", "Young", "Adult", "Old"))`?

Comment: Within this method i get Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  ‘AgeGR’ nie jest gniazdem w klasie “data.frame” - is not a nest in class

Comment: The right function is, cut. Nesting if else statements is lazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same data as above, the better way is to use `?cut`. Repeated ifelse statements will work, but they are inefficient in terms of typing and processing when scaled.

```
df
#   Age
# 1   1
# 2   2
# 3   3
# 4   4
# 5   5

df$AgeGR <- cut(df$Age, c(-Inf, 1,3, Inf), c("Young", "Adult", "Old"))
df
#   Age AgeGR
# 1   1 Young
# 2   2 Adult
# 3   3 Adult
# 4   4   Old
# 5   5   Old
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `grepl` or `sapply`.  But I don't know exactly what conditions you want for that column.  Here's a way to nest `ifelse` statements to satisfy the condition:  If Age <= 1 return "Young", Else If Age > 3 return "Old", Else return "Adult"

```
df$AgeGR <- ifelse(df$Age<=1,"Young",ifelse(df$Age>3,"Old","Adult"))

> df
  Age AgeGR
1   1 Young
2   2 Adult
3   3 Adult
4   4   Old
5   5   Old
```

Comment: Thank you i was fixed on more difficult solution.

Comment: This is a sub optimal fix

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: What if you had 15 different levels to define. Would you write 15 ifelse statements? Use the `?cut` function. It was designed for this specifically.

Comment: Thanks.  For more than 3 or 4 levels, `cut` is a much smarter solution.  OP should know that `cut` will return a factor.  Not a big deal and may even be what they wanted in the end.